# Nested For Loop items and outputting rows

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to loop through a list of items and output them in rows with 5 items per row. The code logic below seems to work, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. I'm also bad at naming my variables so that they're understandable. Any suggestion on how to make my code more semantic and efficient?

```
var items = 15;
var itemsPerRow = 5;
var rows = items/itemsPerRow; 
var lastItemIndex=itemsPerRow;
var j=0;


for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){

   console.log("Row "+(i+1));

   for(;j<lastItemIndex;j++){
     console.log(j);
   }

   lastItemIndex = lastItemIndex + itemsPerRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine, but it is a little unusual.

Another technique would be a loop, an accumulator, and an if:

```
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    if (i%5==0){
        console.log(accumulator);
        accumulator = "";
    else{
        accumulator = accumulator + " " + items[i];
    }
}
```

My syntax and tests might be a little out, so double check everything.

Also I've assumed that your actual items are in an array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to `console.log` without a newline (every `console.log` will start on a separate line).

One solution could be to create a string in the inner loop and then output to the console, like this

```
var items = 15;
var itemsPerRow = 5;
var rows = items/itemsPerRow; 
var lastItemIndex=itemsPerRow;
var j=0;
var singleRow = '';

for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){     
   console.log("Row "+(i+1));

   singleRow = '';
   for(; j<lastItemIndex; j++){
     singleRow += j + ' ';
   }
   console.log(singleRow);

   lastItemIndex = lastItemIndex + itemsPerRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually more efficient to buffer the output and write it all at once but it depends on what you're doing.  For instance when updating an HTML document it makes sense to build an output string and then update the document otherwise you have the document struggling to repaint each time you update it.  The inner for loop is typically done differently but there's nothing wrong with your implementation and the variable names i, j, etc is normal.

```js
var items = 15;
var itemsPerRow = 5;
var rows = items/itemsPerRow; 
var lastItemIndex=itemsPerRow;
var j=0;
var output = "";

for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){
  
  var row = "Row "+(i+1) + "\t";
  
   for(var j = 0; j < itemsPerRow;j++){
     row += j + "\t";
   }
  
  output += row + "\n"
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```